# Inheritance in CoffesScript doesn't correctly work because of lodash merge function

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, coffeescript, lodash

I am programming with Backbone.js in CoffeeScript and have a problem with inheritance in relation with lodash and the merge function.

There is a superclass

```
class NavigationView extends Backbone.View
  config:
    test:
      string: "Test"
```

and two classes derived from it

```
class SubView extends NavigationView

  initialize: ->
      # Setting the view's template property using the Underscore template method
    _.merge @config, {
        test:
          string: "bla"
      }

class IndexView extends NavigationView
...
```

If I change within SubView's function initialize the config variable it is also changed in an instance of IndexView.

I instantiate my objects like so, within a BackBone.Router class:

```
index: () ->
    # Instantiates a new view which will render the header text to the page
    new IndexView()

  sub: () ->
    new SubView()
```

I created a fiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/hijolan/9VeND/

Any ideas how to do that?

Best regards, hijolan

Comment: You have something else going on that you're not showing us. How is your code different than [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vRqGY/)? And you might want to check the indentation in your last code block, correct indentation is very important in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Hey! You were absolutely right... I used the _.merge function from lodash (like underscore.js) to merge the config in my initialize function to merge the parent config and the config in the derived class... after replacing it by the whole config not merged (only for testing purposes) it worked correctly! Thank you for your help...

Comment: The following fiddle shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hijolan/9VeND/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that [`_.merge`](http://lodash.com/docs#merge) modifies its first argument in-place:

> `_.merge(object [, source1, source2, …])`
>
> Merges enumerable properties of the source object(s) into the `destination` object.

Note that where the documentation says `destination` it really means `object`. The intent of `merge` is to be a deep version of [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) and the Underscore docs are explicit about what happens:

> **extend** `_.extend(destination, *sources)`
>
> Copy all of the properties in the **source** objects over to the **destination** object, and return the **destination** object.

You'll notice that lodash's [`extend` (AKA `assign`)](http://lodash.com/docs#assign) also gets the parameter names mixed up:

> `_.assign(object [, source1, source2, …])`
>
> Assigns own enumerable properties of `source` object(s) to the `destination` object.

Again they mean `object` when they say `destination`.

When you do this:

```
class NavigationView extends Backbone.View
  config:
    test:
      string: "Test"
```

The `config` ends up attached to the prototype for `NavigationView` and so the exact same `config` object will be seen by `NavigationView` and its subclasses. That means that `@config` is the prototype's `config` in your `initialize`:

```
_.merge @config, { test: { string1: "blub" } }
```

so `_.merge` will merge the new values right into the prototype's `config` and that makes the change visible all the way up to `NavigationView` and down into all of its subclasses. If you trace the inheritance back up, you'll find that `@config` in that context is from `NavigationView` so your `_.merge` is just a tricky and confusing way of writing:

```
_.merge NavigationView::config, ...
```

The root of the problem is that `_.extend` and `_.merge` modify their first argument. The way out of this trap is to supply a destination object that is safely writeable:

```
@config = _.merge { }, @config, { test: { string1: 'blub' } }
# ----------------^^^
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7j2FM/

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much! On the one hand for the (easy) solution and on the other hand for that perfect and deep ;) explanation!!!!!!!

Comment: If I can't explain it then I don't understand it, if I don't understand it then I can't answer it :) I don't understand why everyone's `extend` behaves this way (even jQuery's [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)) does it, seems very error prone to me and "error prone" shouldn't be the default behavior. I suppose the excuse is performance.